# OS2/Warp - Remotely Stop and Restart a Program

Tags: ibm

Our current phone system runs off of a legacy OS2/Warp box.  Periodically we have to log into the machine and restart OS2RSD.exe and then start it again and the phone system starts working again. The problem is we have to physically get in front of the box and use the GUI to stop and restart the process.  Is it possible to remotely run a script to kill OS2RSD.exe if its running and then start it again?  I have been unable to figure this out on my own.

The OS is OS2/Warp Version 3 if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have the full TCP/IP package loaded, then at the very least you should be able to start up the Telnet service (via the INETD supervisor process, I believe) so that you can connect to the box remotely, get a command prompt, and do your kill/restart that way.  (I know there's a way to kill processes from the command line but I don't remember what it is... been a few years since I did OS/2 stuff.  You can find a process-killer on http://www.os2site.com/sw/util/process/index.html if you don't already have one, though.)

Comment: Yes, I can access the box remotely via telnet.  I will look into the link you provided.